# javascript fetch valid response

Tags: javascript

Below is my javascript code to get the html response

```js
fetch(url + "?" + o)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(html => {
        debugger
        // console.log(html);
        document.getElementById('partialresult').innerHTML = html;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        debugger
        console.log("Can’t access " + url + " response. Blocked by browser?" + err)
        document.getElementById('partialresult').innerHTML = "";
    });
```

Now 500 ( badrequest ) not coming under catch...Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoy can manually resolve or reject a promise with [Promise.prototype.resolve()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject) and [Promise.prototype.reject()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject)

```
fetch(url + "?" + o)
    .then(response => {
        if(response.ok){
          resolve(response.text());
        } else {
          reject();
        }
    })
    .then(html => {
        debugger
        // console.log(html);
        document.getElementById('partialresult').innerHTML = html;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        debugger
        console.log("Can’t access " + url + " response. Blocked by browser?" + err)
        document.getElementById('partialresult').innerHTML = "";
    });
```

Comment: thanks .. redirect is t possible when faiure cases?

Comment: you can execute whatever you want in the catch flow, so for redirect you could use a `window.location.href` or any other rediraction, method

Comment: when `reject()` get executed the flow continues to the next `catch` or `then(x,error)` block, so in your case it will go to the catch block

Comment: last query can i use response.json()  in catch because  if any exception return json like this new { success = false, message = "Operation failed." }..

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `response.ok` is `true` and then parse it.

```
fetch(url + "?" + o).then((response) => {
    if (response.ok){
        debugger
        // console.log(html);
        document.getElementById('partialresult').innerHTML = html;
    }
    else reject();
    
}).catch(()=>{
    debugger
    console.log("Can’t access " + url + " response. Blocked by browser?" + err)
    document.getElementById('partialresult').innerHTML = "";
})
```